# SQL Server populating null values or does not exist values

Tags: sql-server

I have a two table in SQL Server:

TABLE One

```
Weeknumber  Dept        
    1       Sales
    1       Sales
    1       Sales
    2       Transport
    3       Call centre
    4       Sales
    5       Personel
    6       Marketing       
    9       HR
    9       HR
    10      Purchases
```

TABLE Two

```
Weeknumber
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
```

I want to write a query that count the number of dept and if dept is not in table One it should return 0.

As for the example above TABLE ONE. Dept 7 and 8 are missing but I want to include it in my final result to look like the table show below.

Any help please

[table sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD1pD.jpg)

```
Weeknumber  Count_OF_Dept
    1           3
    2           1
    3           1
    4           1
    5           1
    6           1
    7           0
    8           0
    9           2
    10          1
```

Comment: Please See Image for table sample to the questions

Comment: Please share the query/code/whatever what you tried to achieve your goal. Requesting code without showing any effort to solve your problem is for a freelancer site, not for a Q&A site.

Comment: Hi JonWay, as you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. Please go through the answers and vote them up if they are helpful. If one of them helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer, Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this. Just paste this into an empty query window and execute.

ATTENTION: There is a very handsome function to create a running set of numbers, which will be created at the beginning and dropped at the end. Drop it only, if you are sure, that there is not function with this name in your db!

If you do not want to create a new function, just tell, I'll help you to replace it with an "on the fly" solution via CTE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RunningNumbers](@counter INT=1000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    WITH E1(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)), --10 ^ 1
    E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
    E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
    E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
    CteTally AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@counter,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
        FROM E8
    )
    SELECT * FROM CteTally;

GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(WeekNumber INT,Dept VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Sales')
,(1,'Sales')
,(1,'Sales')
,(2,'Transport')
,(3,'Call centre')
,(4,'Sales')
,(5,'Personel')
,(6,'Marketing')   
,(9,'HR')
,(9,'HR')
,(10,'Purchases');

SELECT weekNmbrs.Nmbr
      ,Tbl.WeekNumber
      ,COUNT(Tbl.Dept)
FROM dbo.RunningNumbers(10,1) AS weekNmbrs 
LEFT JOIN @tbl AS Tbl ON weekNmbrs.Nmbr=Tbl.WeekNumber 
GROUP BY weekNmbrs.Nmbr, Tbl.WeekNumber
ORDER BY weekNmbrs.Nmbr ;

--Clean up
/* Are you sure?
DROP FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers; 
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a subquery with `COUNT`:

```
SELECT t2.Weeknumber, 
       Count_OF_Dept = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableOne t1
                        WHERE t1.Weeknumber = t2.Weeknumber)
FROM TableTwo t2
```

Your sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab62b/1/0

Comment: This is the right answer if there is a gap less table of weeknumbers in the system. I think, I misread the question in this point. One up vote from my side...